# MacVim prints 'ls' output whenever run via the 'mvim' command

Tags: ls, macvim

Whenever I launch MacVim via the `mvim` command, I get the output of `ls ~` printed to my terminal repeatedly for as long as I'm using MacVim:

```
$ mvim base.theme.bash 

$ ActiveGSLocalData Music           gtk
Applications        Pictures        lib
Desktop         Public          libexec
Documents       Sites           share
Downloads       Source          src
Dropbox         VirtualBox VMs      tmp
Library         bin
Movies          doc
```

I just ran the `mvim` command on a file, and yet a listing of my home directory gets printed to my terminal. MacVim won't do this unless I'm using it and if I leave it idle, it doesn't. It will do this repeatedly unless I exit the terminal session. I'm using bash and Terminal.app if it matters.

Comment: Is the `vim` command aliased to `ls ~`? Type `alias` to see the current aliases.

Comment: @pavium: No, I have `vim` aliased to `mvim`.